# Strange matching nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm having a lot of problem trying to do something that should be very easy.
I have these 3 csv:
First one, Cast CSV ~ 150k records

```
idActor,idMovie,nameActor,character
"10990","321612","Belle","Emma Watson"
"221018","321612","Beast","Dan Stevens"
"114019","321612","Gaston","Luke Evans"
"8945","321612","Maurice","Kevin Kline"
```

Second one, Actor CSV ~ 8k records.

```
idActor,deathday,gender,birthday,name,place_of_birth,popularity
"10990","null","1","1990-04-15","Emma Watson","Paris; France","54.327581"
"114019","null","2","1979-04-15","Luke Evans","Pontypool; Wales; UK","13.145154"
"54415","null","2","1981-02-23","Josh Gad","Hollywood; Florida; USA","11.418704"
"2283","null","2","1960-11-11","Stanley Tucci","Peekskill; New York; USA","11.013948"
"221018","null","2","1982-10-10","Dan Stevens","Croydon; Surrey; England; UK","27.461241"
"3061","null","2","1971-03-31","Ewan McGregor","Perth; Scotland; UK","18.398385"
```

And the last one, Movie CSV ~ 10k records.

(Header - 1 line)
    idMovie,overview,popularity,companies,
    countries,release_date,revenue,runtime,tagline,vote_average, 
    vote_count,budget,genre,title

```
"99861","When Tony Stark tries to jumpstart a dormant peacekeeping program, things go awry and Earth’s Mightiest Heroes are put to the ultimate test as the fate of the planet hangs in the balance. As the villainous Ultron emerges, it is up to The Avengers to stop him from enacting his terrible plans, and soon uneasy alliances and unexpected action pave the way for an epic and unique global adventure.","10.836173","Marvel Studios;Prime Focus;Revolution Sun Studios","US","2015-04-22","1405035767","141","A New Age Has Come.","7.3","5868","280000000","Action;Adventure;Science Fiction","Avengers: Age of Ultron"
```

After doing import in Neo4j, converting the necessary field into Integer or Float, I want to do some relationship.

For example,

```
MATCH (m:Movie), (c:CastMember), (a:Actor)
WHERE m.idMovie = c.idMovie AND a.idActor = c.idActor
CREATE (a)-[:HAS_ACTED_IN{character:c.character}]->(m)
```

But it create just ~50 relationships, instead of more than 100k.

So, I made other attemps, in particular:

```
MATCH (m:Movie), (c:CastMember)
WHERE m.idMovie = c.idMovie
RETURN DISTINCT m.title
```

returns just ~20 matches.

Again,

```
MATCH (c:CastMember), (a:Actor)
WHERE c.idActor = a.idActor
RETURN a.name
```

returns just ~5 matches.

The matches change every time I import the CSV. That's very strange.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/where/) about `WHERE` says:

> `WHERE` adds constraints to the patterns in a `MATCH` or `OPTIONAL MATCH` 
>   clause or filters the results of a WITH clause.

So you can use more than one `WHERE` per Cypher query. I believe this is your case. I would try something like:

```
MATCH (c:CastMember)
MATCH (a:Actor)
WHERE a.idActor = c.idActor
MATCH (m:Movie)
WHERE m.idMovie = c.idMovie 
CREATE (a)-[:HAS_ACTED_IN{character:c.character}]->(m)
```

Comment: 0 Relationship created, in this way. That's crazy. a.idActor and c.idActor are both Integer (I have used toInteger when I loaded the CSV), and same thing for m.idActor and c.idMovie...

Comment: @randy192 Try it:

`MATCH (c:CastMember)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a:Actor)
WHERE a.idActor = c.idActor
OPTIONAL MATCH (m:Movie)
WHERE m.id = c.idMovie 
CREATE (a)-[:HAS_ACTED_IN{character:c.character}]->(m)`

Comment: nothing to do... this time: "Expected to find a node at m but found nothing Some(null)"
Thank you for you help anyway :(

Answer (score 0):

So, you should have :

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (a:Actor) ASSERT a.idActor IS UNIQUE;
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (m:Movie) ASSERT m.idMovie IS UNIQUE;
```

and then loaded actors and movies with LOAD CSV ... did you count afterwards ... and those numbers are checking out ?

And then you can create the relationship directory in the LOAD CSV of the cast :

```
LOAD CSV ... AS line
MATCH (m:Movie {idMovie : line.idMovie})
MATCH (a:Actor {idActor : line.idActor})
MERGE (a)-[:HAS_ACTED_IN {character: line.character}]->(m);
```

I note the following things as well :

1. The headers on the cast csv are not in the correct order
2. The WHERE m.id = c.idMovie AND a.idActor = c.idActor can not work as
   it should be m.idMovie

but those might be typos.

Hope this helps,
Tom

Comment: The node are unique. I have removed the node with the same idActor, before executing the COUNT() function.

1. My fault, but there are no condition about character, or nameActor, so...
2. Corrected, the error was just in the post.